# Rails vs CodeIgniter performance when retrieving many records

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, codeigniter

**EDIT - This is not a thread meant to bash Rails!  I love Rails and I am merely trying to fully understand the differences.**

**EDIT 2 - Found a pretty neat article, it looks like it may have everything to do with how objects are instanciated verse having a simple classes or multidimensional arrays. http://merbist.com/2012/02/23/quick-dive-into-ruby-orm-object-initialization/**

I recently began converting to Ruby/Rails from PHP/Codeigniter.  I am mainly just playing with Rails now to get a feeling of how it works.

My initial concerns are performance.  I have a "locations" model which stores some information about a location.  Around 10 varchar columns.  There's a total of **4000** records.  I set up two quick tests comparing CodeIgniter and Rails.

In the **ruby/rails** locations index view, I run `Location.all`.  If I then render an empty view the initial response time on the page is around 400-500ms.  Without the `Location.all` is a steady 20ms.

In **php/codeigniter** I can do the exact same thing ( `$this->db->get('locations')->result_array()` )., and the initial response on the page is around 100ms. Without actually pulling up all the records my response time is a steady 30ms.

I know it's probably not realistic to ever actually load up 4000 records at once, but it scares me that there is that much difference in performance.  Can anyone explain what is happening and if there is something I can do to avoid this.  100ms verse 500ms is a 5x performance difference!  I love rails so far, so don't take this as a bashing, just trying to wrap my head around it.

**RUBY/RAILS screenshot**

[image: ruby/rails]

**PHP/CODEIGNITER**

[image: php/codeigniter]

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP is presumably being served by Apache and it seems your Rails app is served by WEBrick. WEBrick is not optimized for stuff like this.

Comment: I am current using "Thin, Straight Razor". When you say not optimized, could you explain what you mean.

Comment: As you are running Rails locally, there are a number of things which may be going on in development that significantly slow processing - for example verbose logging.  Other than that you are comparing apples and oranges.  I suggest you take a look at that verbose log while Rails runs to see all the things it is doing - how it probes the database schema and generates queries.

Comment: Other thing to note is that when running in development, your Rails stack is likely recompiling your application on each run, which is really time consuming. In a production environment, that would not be happening and performance may differ drastically. The PHP interpreter runs the same way in either circumstance, so its performance won't vary much.

Comment: i get very similar results on my staging server which is a linode box running Puma.  staging is set to production. i dont understand why so many people are trying to close the thread.  it seems like a valid concern. im not moving away from rails.. just trying to understand the difference in performance and how/why it is that way.

Comment: Just made simple example with 6000 objects with 10 attributes in each. And got result after processing void index on all of them: `Completed 200 OK in 881ms (Views: 880.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)` Do you have something simmilar? Point of view is ActiveRecord time. If I reload page it shows: `Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Are you saying if you reload the same page you got form 800ms to 6.7ms? Sounds like you have caching going on maybe?  But I think you see the initial problem of 800ms to pull up 6000 objects (and do nothing with them)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Location.all` it is instantiating 4000 objects; a lot happens when you instantiate an object in rails.

If you care about performance in your app you will likely be doing a lot of caching, whether you use php or rails.  In a situation like this where you are loading a large amount of objects, you can use something like IdentityCache to cache them:

https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache

Cheers,

Comment: I do believe that the instanciating of objects verse having a simple data array may be the difference.  Is there a very significant difference between an array of objects in Ruby verse a multidimensional data array in PHP?